# Filtering by date email added to mailbox, not actual email received date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am able to successfully receive a list of emails received after a particular date, by adding

```
&filter=receivedDateTime ge 2019-12-15T21:01:15Z
```

to the messages url.

The problem is if I drag an old email from a different mailbox to this processing mailbox, the received date will be the original received date.

As I am attempting to only process emails in the mailbox that have arrived since the last time I've processed, this "new" email will not be included. I need it to be.

Is there another filter I can apply that will allow me to capture all emails added to the mailbox, since a particular date and time? Something like

```
&filter=mailboxReceivedDateTime ge 2019-12-15T21:01:15Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the createdDateTime this property doesn't represent the time the Message was created but the time the item was added to a Folder collection. Because of the way moves are handled in Exchange this property should get updated when you move an Item between folders (like the ItemId does). eg try a simple query like this in the Graph Explorer and move an old message back and forth between two mailbox folders. You should see the old message pop to the top of the returned items when you move it back to the Inbox

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$orderby=createdDateTime desc
```

Comment: The createdDateTime property did not change in my tests. use lastModifiedDateTime instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `lastModifiedDateTime` field.

`receivedDateTime` and `createdDateTime` don't change when dragging a message between folders according to my tests with Office365 account on Graph API.

Remember this can be triggered by other changes too, so you should use a mechanism to prevent duplicate entries.